# Visualization problem in #graphdb : This node has no visible connections

Tags: visualization, graphdb

I'm using graphdb to visualize connections between my nodes, but when I used visual graph and I tape an IRI, a single node appear although I know it has several connections but they do not appear.

Architecture screenshot:

[image: Architecture screenshot]

Node screenshot]:

[image: Node screenshot]